# Mathematica reading my mind - Solve knows which variable to solve for

Tags: equation-solving

I was checking some of my algebra with the following code;

```
ClearAll[Nx, Ny, Nz, mx, my, mz, M, H, H0, ω, γ]
coup1 = {{(I ω)/γ, H0 - ms (Ny - Nz), 0}, {-H0 - ms (Nx - Ny), (I ω)/γ, 0}, {0, 0, (I ω)/γ}};
Solve[Det[coup1] == 0]
```

and was reassured that I can indeed still do things on paper by the output

```
{{ω->0},{ω->-Sqrt[H0+ms Nx-ms Ny] Sqrt[H0-ms Ny+ms Nz] γ},{ω->Sqrt[H0+ms Nx-ms Ny] Sqrt[H0-ms Ny+ms Nz] γ}}
```

But then I realised that I hadn't told Solve which variable I wanted to solve for. It is quite correct, I do indeed want to solve for $\omega$, but how did it know? I can explicitly order it to solve for the other variables, and it will do so quite happily.

On the other hand, if the last line is

```
Solve[Det[coup1] == ms]
```

then it finds sets of solutions which involve an assortment of variables. What is going on under the bonnet$^*$ here?

$^*$ 'under the hood', in American English, I suppose.

Comment: Look at `Det[coup1]`. It is a product an from this it is quite clear under what conditions this product is zero ;-)

Comment: Might be it was the first one encountered in the expression.

Comment: It seems that `Solve` would find the most "obvious" solution if vars are omitted.  for example  `Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0]` gives `{{a -> (-1 - x^2)/x}}`